# Geokettle Data Input from Oracle Database

Tags: ogr, oracle-dbms, geokettle

i just installed GeoKettle and am trying to do some first steps in this.
Can anyone help me with the data input step to an Oracle DB?

I tried the OGR Input:
[image]

But i seem to be unable to find the right syntax for the connection.
Can anyone help me with the Data Source (maybe giving an exampl)?
And what exactly do i have to fill in at "Layer Name"? The table name in my database? (i integrated the table , A37_SIREN_UTM in my data source in my example, but putting it in as the layer name didnt work too.)

Another option would be the Table Input:
[image]

The ODBC connection geodaten is defined on my computer.
But here too i am unable to connect to the DB.

Comment: I guess you have to provide the host-computer where the db is located on `DNS source name`. Before chosing a layer test the connection.

Comment: Ok, i solved it.
I queried my database with:

SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SERVER_HOST') FROM dual;

Comment: Ok, i solved it.
I queried my database with:

SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SERVER_HOST') FROM dual;

and

SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','DB_NAME') FROM dual; 

and filled in the results for "ODBC DSN Source Name" and "Tablespace for Data", respectively (using the Table Input step).

Of course i needed to enter user and password too.

Comment: You may answer your own question so that future reads quickly will find it if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you have said in comments, the answer here is first to obtain the relevant information by running two SQL queries directly on the database:

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SERVER_HOST') FROM dual;
/* Gives you "ODBC DSN Source Name" */

SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','DB_NAME') FROM dual;
/* Gives you "Tablespace for Data" */
```

Then use this information in the GeoKettle Database Connection form together with the User Name and Password